# How can I color the borders of an item in a grid so that it replaces the borders of the parent container?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to highlight an individual cell by giving it a green border when it has a specific class. But the borders of the cell are not replacing the borders of the parent container.

I tried to give the cell a border with 1px and solid green. This is how it looks: [My current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eoFy.png)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you show the markup and CSS? That might help to zero in on the fix a bit faster.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. As suggested above, please can you post your code but there's enough information in your image to know what the problem is. Grid is great but developers often style the whole grid container then style the grid item borders to give us the style we want. This works but for the hover event, the elements live inside the grid so if you change the borders using :hover, the border of the child element sits inside the parent.

If you need to highlight the border of one child element on hover then you have to style the child borders only and leave the parent grid container alone.  There is a 'gotcha', unfortunately, setting both border-top and border-bottom gives you a double-width border between items. To get around this you have to style one border only then using the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to style the next border below.  See annotated code below:

```css
.container {
  /* this is the parent container, we don't style any borders on this */
  width: fit-content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.container > div {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-bottom-style:none; /* we have to set this to none otherwise we'll get a double thickness border between both elements */
  
  /* just some styling below to make it look like your example */
  padding: 0.5rem; 
  width: 20ch;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.container > div:first-child {
  border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 0;  /*apply fancy curving style to the top */
}

.container > div:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 1rem 1rem;  /* fancy styling at the bottom */
  border-bottom-style: solid; /* because this is the last element we have to add a border at the bottom */
}

.container > div:hover {
  border-color:red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container > div:hover + div {
  border-top-color:red;  /* we have also style the next element below's border too on hover so we use the adjacent sibling combinator (+) here. */
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>Section 1</div>
  <div>Section 2</div>
  <div>Section 3</div>
  <div>Section 4</div>
  <div>Section 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much, I was struggling for a week with this and I am a React Developer since 2 years ^^